# Textbox not aligned in ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

This is how my textboxes are appeared in the gridview, they are not aligned in the columns.

[image]
[Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SWiK.jpg)

I am adding the textboxes in the footer template.

Can you please help me how to fix this?

Thanks.

Here's the code of my griview, you can check any column having textbox in the footer template.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gridService" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="table table-bordered" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="gridService_RowCancelingUpdate" OnRowCreated="gridService_RowCreated" OnRowDeleting="gridService_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gridService_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gridService_RowUpdating" PageSize="8" ShowFooter="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameNewText" runat="server" Class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="UserPasswordLabel" runat="server" Text="****"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserPasswordtext" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserPassword")%>' TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserPasswordNewText" runat="server" Class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Admin Module" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="AdminModuleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AdminModule")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="AdminModuleckb" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("AdminModule").ToString() == "True" ? true : false %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="AdminModulenewckb" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enrollees Module" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="EnrolleesModuleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EnrolleesModule")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="EnrolleesModuleckb" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("EnrolleesModule").ToString() == "True" ? true : false %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="EnrolleesModulenewckb" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transactions Module" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="TransactionsModuleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TransactionsModule")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="TransactionsModuleckb" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("TransactionsModule").ToString() == "True" ? true : false %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="TransactionsModulenewckb" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Configuration Module" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ConfigurationModuleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ConfigurationModule")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ConfigurationModuleckb" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("ConfigurationModule").ToString() == "True" ? true : false %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ConfigurationModulenewckb" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Statistics Module" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="StatisticsModuleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StatisticsModule")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="StatisticsModuleckb" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("StatisticsModule").ToString() == "True" ? true : false %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="StatisticsModulenewckb" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/Content/images/cancel.png" EditImageUrl="~/Content/images/edit.png" ShowEditButton="True" UpdateImageUrl="~/Content/images/update.png" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkremove" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Username")%>' CommandName="delete" ImageUrl="~/Content/images/delete.png" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?')" Visible='<%# Eval("Username").ToString() == "Admin" ? false : true %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" OnClick="AddService" Text="Add" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <%--<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton='<%# Eval("Username").ToString() == "admin" ? true : false %>' ButtonType="Image"  DeleteImageUrl="~/Content/images/delete.png"/>--%>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Below is the related css.

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #8e8e93;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #c7c7cc;
  border-radius: 4px;  
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

Comment: Please put the html tag for gridview and css if any

Comment: You'll need to share you footer template markup along with any classes you are using. If you cant share code, check your widths and css classes definitions and make sure you are aligned the same as the item templates etc. If you are wantig to hide something before the textboxes suggest using style="display:none"

Comment: I have edited my original post and put code and css over there. Please let me know fi anything else is needed to fix this problem.